# OpenVPN with LAMP on same VPS instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, vps, lamp

I have a VPS where I configured LAMP to host a couple of websites. Would it be problematic to set an OpenVPN Access Server on this same server, alongside LAMP?

If this is a good idea at all? What should I take into account to avoid having issues?

I've heard it could cause trouble for PHP communicating with MySQL databases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of this OpenVPN access server?

Comment: Private use as a personal VPN as well as educational purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install it on the same server. Problems with database might occur if you have overlapping IP networks on the OpenVPN configuration and private network in your server setup. That is, if your MySQL server is on a separate server than PHP, and the IP network overlaps with OpenVPN.

Normal LAMP setup on a single host uses Unix sockets for communication between OpenVPN and PHP, and that cannot be affected by OpenVPN.

So, you just need to take care that there aren't overlapping IP networks.